# oracle object no longer exists

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

in my pl\sql process, there is an execution of "alter table exchange parition.."
on some table.

the problem is that during that operation - other users can try to access the target table.

one process that executed a select query on that table, got this error:
ORA-08103 object no longer exists.

i think that it is not the same like 'object or view doesn't exist'.

i think that 'object no longer exists' error, come when the process start ok,

and then the exchange (or other operation) come from the side and the process

can't bo done.

the chance is very low that it will happen, because the exchange is very very fast.

but for this case, there is any idea how to solve it? how to prevent this situation?

maybe a way to execute the exchange only if no-one touch the table?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when session #2 alters the table in the table after session #1 has opened its cursor but before it is finished fetching the rows from that cursor.

I don't think there is a foolproof way to prevent the exchange from happening unless you are willing to change the code that other users are using to access the target table.

`LOCK TABLE mytable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` will not wait for `SELECT` statements to complete, nor will it prevent new `SELECT` statements from starting, so acquiring an exclusive lock before attempting the `ALTER TABLE` will not work.

If you want to prevent the `ALTER TABLE` from happening at the same time as `SELECT`s, you need both to depend on acquiring the same lock.  A relatively robust way to do that would be to use the `DBMS_LOCK` package to allocate a lock for that table.  Call that lock "mytablelock".

Then, using DBMS_LOCK, your `SELECT` sessions would need to acquire "shared" locks on "mytablelock" before progressing.  Your `alter table` sessions would need to acquire an "exclusive" lock on "mytablelock" before progressing.

This scheme would allow multiple `SELECT` sessions to run without interfering with each other, but it would prevent the `ALTER TABLE` from running while any `SELECT` was running.

A (much) less robust, but simpler, way to do it would be to change the `SELECT` statements issued from the other query into `SELECT FOR UPDATES`.  But that's a recipe for lots of unnecessary waits and deadlock errors.

Comment: is it mean that for every process that makes a select on this table, i will need to add operation of dbms_lock ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: it's a big problem for me to do that. Maybe there is a good way to check if the target table is in-use right now, and give a sleep to my alter process?

Comment: I cannot think of one without resorting to internal `X$` tables, which I won't recommend or publish.  My recommendation: if you need your `SELECT` statements to work without fail, don't issue DML statements while the system is online.

Comment: After thinking about it some more, you might be able to use online redefinition (`DBMS_REDEFINITION` package) to do the `ALTER TABLE`.  I don't have time to look at that right now.

Comment: my first purpose was to switch between to tables. there is the current data table ("target table") that users and processes access to it. and when new data need to insert to that table (not add, but replace) i load this data to new table ("load table"). i create it in a process, and it contains 1 partition for all rows. the purpose is to do exchange partition from the load_table to the target (replace all rows - target table has no partitions). but it fail on the no longer exist.now with the redefinition when execute the finish_redef_table procedure-the exception come again cause table droped